# how to auto increment id values only if id values are new in table.That is i want only repetitive records column to be auto incremented

Tags: sql-server

Please check the table on the picture below:

[image: Click for the table used]

So I want incremented value only if repetitive value is encountered i.e sru8888. Which gives me sru88881 and sru88881. But the incremented value is the same continuing to sru777979 as sru777979**3** as well.
I want this number to be incremented from 1. So want the o/p value to be sru777979**1**.

My current table and stored procedure are here:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Test1]
(
    [IncidentNumber] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY NOT NULL, 
    [JournalEntryNumber] as IncidentNumber + Cast(ID as Varchar(10)) PERSISTED PRIMARY KEY,
    [JournalType] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [JournalDescription] [nvarchar](max) NULL
)

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_JournalCreated]
       @IncidentNumber VARCHAR(50), 
       @JournalType nvarchar(max) = NULL, 
       @JournalDescription nvarchar(max) = NULL
AS
BEGIN 
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[Test1](IncidentNumber, JournalType, JournalDescription) 
    VALUES (@IncidentNumber, @JournalType, @JournalDescription) 
END
GO
```

Comment: Not very clear what you are asking, try to explain the problem using a current dataset and the expected output. You say you want to increment values by 1 how do you get the value `sru7779791`  from values `sru777979` and `sru7779793`.

Comment: This seems like a pretty brittle key structure. What happens when you run into duplicate values because you already have an IncidentNumber value that will cause a conflict? It is almost always a bad idea to make your primary key derived off values that can end up with duplicates so easily.

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: I agree with @SeanLange This structure hints to being better served by having an Incident table that is a foreign key reference to Test1, which is probable named better named something like IncidentEntry. and i see no natural key value in IncidentNumber being varchar so better that column be numeric anyways, at least how it relates to a some other obvious entity (aka the incident).

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you cannot use the `IDENTITY`type. You need to write an **Insert Trigger** which does the sequence logic.

Comment: fair point to make however i wonder if this route were taken is it just enabling a bad design vs fixing the underlying structural problem of this odd varchar + int primary key

Comment: @hubsonbropa that's right and true for many questions here. Instead of answering the question itself, one should ask what is the underlying idea of it and how could it possibly be better designed ?